# Como agregar y quitar Javascript de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web que necesita cargar modulos de forma dinamica, cada modulo tiene fragmentos de codigo html, css, javascript, los cuales los cargo via ajax con json:

Para agregar el html y el css el método innerHTML me funciona perfectamente, cosa que no pasa con el Javascript.

aqui les dejo el codigo de la peticion y respuesta:

```
//esta seria la peticion
function requestApplication(e){
    var solicitud = new XMLHttpRequest();
    solicitud.addEventListener('load', requestAplicacionResponse, false);
    var aplicacion = e.target;
    var modulo = aplicacion.parentNode.parentNode;
    var sucursal = modulo.parentNode.parentNode;
    var dataset = sucursal.dataset;
    var url = 'http://' + dataset.host + ':' + dataset.port + '/sistema/aplicacion';
    var paquete = {
        'sesion':sucursal.dataset.sesion,
        'usuario':sucursal.dataset.usuario,
        'perfil': sucursal.dataset.perfil,
        'modulo': modulo.dataset.modulo,
        'aplicacion': aplicacion.dataset.aplicacion
    };
    solicitud.open('POST', url);
    solicitud.send(JSON.stringify(paquete));
}

//este metodo recibe la respuesta del servidor
function requestAplicacionResponse(e){
    var main = document.querySelector('main');//contenedor donde quiero agregar lo solicitado
    //obj es un diccionario clave valor "objeto json" que contiene el codigo que deseo agregar
    var obj = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
    main.innerHTML = main.innerHTML + obj.html + obj.css + obj.js;
}
```

se visualiza correctamente pero no tiene funcionalidad, aparentemente parece que no se agregaran las funciones javascript al interprete javascript asociada con el DOM de la pagina.

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene el JavaScript que recibes?¿Y cómo intentas ponerlo en la página?

Comment: Puedes darnos un ejemplo de tu codigo tambien, por favor?

Comment: sobre el formato de la respuesta seria algo asi: el html es una etiqueta div que dentro tiene varios elelemtos html,   el css es una etiqueta style con el codigo css necesario para estilizar al html, y el javascript en una etiqueta script que contiene el código javacript que requiere.   todo esto esta en formato texto o cadena de caracteres. todo debidamente abierto y cerrado correctamente.

Comment: @Nayer, luego de ver tu codigo te deje un ejemplo que puede ayudarte a cargar el contenido que ya recibes por ajax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No es posible agregar javascript via `innerHTML`. debes cargar el script como archivo separado o como una etiqueta con texto. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Salu2

## Aregar como etiqueta con contenido:

```js
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.text = 'alert("hola mundo")';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
```

## Agregar como archivo.

Creas una etiqueta `<script>` y la agregas al `<head>`. El evento `onload` te indica cuando se completo la carga del script.

```
// agregamos archivo-ltr.css o archivo-rtl.css
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = '/ruta/al/archivo.js';
script.onload = function () {
   // el script se ha cargado 
};

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
```

## Eliminar

Buscas la etiqueta `<script>` que quieres eliminar y la eliminas. Ten en cuanta que esto no implica que el modulo esta totalmente descargado, solo el fuente fue descargado, cualquier instancia u variable global declarada en ese modulo sigue existiendo.

```
var script = document.querySelector('script[src=/ruta/al/archivo.js]')
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregas funciones javascript en tiempo de ejecución éstas no se relacionan con los objetos, lo que debes hacer es darle bind a los objetos DESPUÉS de agregar las funciones nuevas. Revisa http://api.jquery.com/bind/